# Adding redirect rule to htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, cpanel

I have several domains pointed to my hosting. Suppose I have ex1.com, ex2.com, ex3.com pointed to my hosting. Now ex2.com is hosted on another hosting. Now I want to add a redirect rule on the htaccess file so that I can redirect ex1.com to ex2.com. What will be the code? I tried the code below but no luck :-

RewriteEngine on

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ex1.com [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.ex1.com [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.ex2.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Can anyone please inform me what I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

You require Redirect 301:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !newdomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This is useful when you use www.newdomain.com as your new domain name. If the domain is different, then use:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain\.com$ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.olddomain\.com$
  RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Obviously replace olddomain and newdomain with the correct domains.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I figured it out :)

Comment: That's great @Gamer I would appreciate you selecting my answer as correct. Therefore helping others who come across this question and knowing the correct answer.